# Red Pass Filter for Image Processing in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to code a Red Pass filer in C#. I might not be using the correct name for this, but I want to convert all the non-red pixel to black (0,0,0).

So, like how a high pass filter sets all frequencies below a giving setpoint to 0.  I want to set all the non-red pixel to (0,0,0) aka Black.

My problem is that I am using images from a camera, so the red pixels are not (255,0,0) plus because of Light and shades on the object I am taking a picture of some of the red pixels are darker than others. Meaning this [Red Color] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc42q.png) and this [Red Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgn4B.png) are on the same object in the image.

This is what I have Tried so for:

```
public bool IsRed(RGB color)
{
    // The pixel is a shade of red if the red value is greater than the green and blue values
    return color.Red > color.Green && color.Red > color.Blue;
}

public bool IsRed2(RGB color)
{
    // The pixel is a shade of red if the red value is within the range of 128 to 255.
    return color.Red >= 128 && color.Red <= 255;
}

public bool IsRed3(RGB color)
{
    // Convert the RGB values to HSL.
    double hue, saturation, lightness;
    RGBToHSL(color.Red, color.Green, color.Blue, out hue, out saturation, out lightness);

    // The pixel is a shade of red if the hue is within the range of 0 to 30 degrees or 330 to 360 degrees.
    return (hue >= 0 && hue <= 30) || (hue >= 330 && hue <= 360);
}

// Converts the given RGB values to HSL.
private void RGBToHSL(byte red, byte green, byte blue, out double hue, out double saturation, out double lightness)
{
    // Convert the RGB values to the range 0 to 1.
    double r = red / 255.0;
    double g = green / 255.0;
    double b = blue / 255.0;

    // Calculate the maximum and minimum RGB values.
    double max = Math.Max(r, Math.Max(g, b));
    double min = Math.Min(r, Math.Min(g, b));

    // Calculate the lightness.
    lightness = (max + min) / 2;

    // Calculate the saturation.
    if (max == min)
    {
        // The color is a shade of gray.
        hue = 0;
        saturation = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // The color is not a shade of gray.
        double d = max - min;
        saturation = lightness > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);

        // Calculate the hue.
        if (max == r)
        {
            hue = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
        }
        else if (max == g)
        {
            hue = (b - r) / d + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            hue = (r - g) / d + 4;
        }

        hue /= 6;
    }
}
```

Update :
This is how I am getting the RGB values from the image:

```
  private RGB[,] ImageToRGBByteArray(Bitmap _image, int height, int width)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(_image);

        BitmapData bData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _image.Width, _image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);

        /* GetBitsPerPixel just does a switch on the PixelFormat and returns the number */
        BitsPerPixel = GetBitsPerPixel(bData.PixelFormat);

        /*the size of the image in bytes */
        int size = bData.Stride * bData.Height;

        Stride = bData.Stride;
        /*Allocate buffer for image*/
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        RGB[,] imagematrix = new RGB[height, width];
        int[,] imageData = new int[height, width];
        /*This overload copies data of /size/ into /data/ from location specified (/Scan0/)*/
        Marshal.Copy(bData.Scan0, data, 0, size);
        int i = 0;

        ModifiedHistogram = null;
        ImageData = null;
        ImageRGBData = null;
        Dictionary<RGB, int> modifiedHistogram = new Dictionary<RGB, int>();

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                RGB tempValue = new RGB(data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]);
                imagematrix[y, x] = tempValue;

                imageData[y, x] = (int)((data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2]) / 3D);

                if (!modifiedHistogram.ContainsKey(tempValue))
                    modifiedHistogram.Add(tempValue, 1);
                else
                    modifiedHistogram[tempValue]++;
                i += BitsPerPixel / 8;
            }
        }

        int maxValue = 0;
        string color = string.Empty;
        foreach (var kvp in modifiedHistogram)
        {
            if (kvp.Value > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = kvp.Value;
                color = kvp.Key.ColorName;
            }
        }
        ImageData = imageData;
        ImageRGBData = imagematrix;
        ModifiedHistogram = modifiedHistogram;
        return imagematrix;
    }
```

So

```
data[i] = Red
data[i+2] = Green 
data[i+3] = Blue
```

This is my Color class

```
   public class RGB
{
    public  byte Red { get; set; }
    public  byte Green { get; set; }
    public  byte Blue { get; set; }



    public RGB(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
    {
        Red = red;
        Green = green;
        Blue = blue;
        SetColorName();
    }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         RGB other = obj as RGB;
        return other != null && other.ColorName == this.ColorName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like most of your problem is defining which part of the RGB or HSV colour space you define as being "red".

Comment: @ Jeremy Lakeman, what do you mean?

Comment: eg which geometric volume of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_spaces cube or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV cylinder counts as red. Then your code is simply trying to answer "is this point inside this volume".

Comment: @ Jeremy Lakeman, I just updated  my post to show how I am defining Red, Green, Blue. is this what you are asking?

Comment: No, I mean "RED" is a subjective human concept https://i0.wp.com/imgs.xkcd.com/blag/satfaces_map_450.png. Your first problem is to define what you mean by "RED" in terms of the abstract geometry of color (as above). Once you have a definition, writing a test to filter pixels is a coding problem this site could help you with.

Comment: If you can't find an efficient way of doing this, consider using a professional imaging SDK such as LEADTOOLS. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). There's [a forum post here](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/m51906-) that shows how Hue values can be used to keep the red pixels in an image and fill all others with black. If you'd like to try the project, the SDK has [a free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).